# Automated organizer for downloads folder causing all chrome downloads to fail

Tags: python, automation, scripting

I am still fairly new to programming and decided to write a script that would benefit me personally while also testing my ability. I created a script that uses watchdog to track the downloads folder on my machine. I wanted to make it as dynamic as I could so I could in theory give the program to friends, and they could enter their desired paths into the .txt file that accompanies it and it would continue to work seamlessly for them. I have the program working in a sense; if I drag a picture file from one folder into the downloads folder, it will automatically send it to the Pictures folder. My problem arises with new downloads. Any time I try to download a picture on chrome while the script is running I get 'Failed- Download Error'. I have been trying to figure out what this is for a few hours now and finally decided to try and seek some advice.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import time
from shutil import move


paths_dict = {'dl_path': [], 'img_path': [], 'audio_path': [], 'vid_path': [],
              'doc_path': [], 'exe_path': [], 'zip_path': [], 'other_path': []}
keys = list(paths_dict.keys())

val_list = []
p_len = len(paths_dict.keys())


with open('config.txt', 'r') as paths:
    for line in paths.readlines():
        line.strip()
        split = list(line.split())
        path = split[-1]
        val_list.append(path)

    while p_len != 0:
        for k in keys:
            paths_dict[k].append(val_list[0])
            val_list.remove(val_list[0])
            p_len -= 1

image_formats = ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif", "webp", "tiff", "bmp",
                 "heif", "jfif", "bat", "webp", "tiff"]
audio_formats = ["mp3", "wav", "ogg", "flac", "m4a", "aac"]
video_formats = ["mp4", "avi", "webm", "mov", 'mkv']
docs_formats = ["ai", "ait", "rtf", "txt", "doc", "docx", "pdf"]
executables = ["exe"]
zip_folders = ["zip", "tar", "gz", "7z"]


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):

        for file in os.listdir(paths_dict['dl_path'][0]):
            extension = (file.split('.')[-1].lower())
            src = paths_dict['dl_path'][0] + '\\' + file

            if extension in image_formats:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['img_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)

            elif extension in video_formats:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['vid_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)

            elif extension in docs_formats:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['doc_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)

            elif extension in executables:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['exe_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)

            elif extension in zip_folders:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['zip_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)

            else:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['other_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)


event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, paths_dict['dl_path'][0], recursive=False)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

This is what is contained in my .txt file for context:

```
Path to downloads folder: C:\Users\12483\Downloads
Path of where downloaded image files are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\Pictures
Path of where downloaded audio files are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\Music
Path of where downloaded video files are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\Videos
Path of where downloaded document files are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\Documents
Path of where downloaded executable files are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\exe_files
Path of where downloaded zip files are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\zip_files
Path of where all other file types are to be stored: C:\Users\12483\misc_files
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually kind of a cool idea...

As someone with not a lot of experience with using python for file management.  I don't think I'll be able to modify your code directly competently, but I have a theory.

When a browser starts downloading a file it begins by creating a template that is only part of the file called a .part file.

[https://fileinfo.com/extension/part#:~:text=A%20PART%20file%20is%20a,program%20that%20started%20the%20download.](https://fileinfo.com/extension/part#:%7E:text=A%20PART%20file%20is%20a,program%20that%20started%20the%20download.)

I assume that your python script is attempting to organize this file before the download can complete.

So the solution(theoretically) would be to modify your script to wait for the .part file to become the correct type, perhaps by ignoring files with .part

Edit:

i need rubber ducky brought up another type of partial file that we would want to ignore.(.crdownload) There could easily be more.

Here's one possible solution:

Declare

```
partial_files = ["crdownload", "part"]
```

Then in your for loop:

```
            elif extension in zip_folders:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['zip_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)

            # new code
            elif extension in partial_files:
                 pass # this essentially means do nothing
            # /new code
            else:
                folder_dst = paths_dict['other_path'][0]
                new_dst = folder_dst + '\\' + file
                move(src, new_dst)
```

Comment: Earlier I found that Chrome, Edge, etc. (chromium based) generate a '.crdownload'. So I attempted to implement a while loop to wait for it to download. Something along the lines of setting wait = True before the loop and then initiates a while loop based on that. Basically as long as .crdownload is in the Downloads folder then it will remain True, once it's done it would go False and in theory break the loop. I removed it from the code because it didn't seem to have any effect. That does make sense as the answer to the problem, I must not have much of an idea on how to implement it in context.

Comment: A while loop pause is bad practice. But this is coming from someone that doesn't know much about thread management in Python, so I don't really know why that solution wouldn't work.  I updated my answer with another idea... Good luck.